# My domain has a redirector to reddit.local

Tags: python, ubuntu, open-source, reddit

everyone,

I installed [reddit](https://github.com/reddit/reddit) on my server and I point the domain to my server but when I access my domain it has a redirection to "reddit.local".

I miss to do something ? Why not access my installation and redirect to reddit.local ?

Comment: You would need to provide more information, how did you install it? 
Which web-server  are you using? what is reddit.local?

Comment: I linked "reddit" to github repository to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the install script, it will ask you for the domain name you want to use; I assume you left it at the default of `reddit.local`?

Have you changed [the domain setting](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/example.ini#L89) in your config file?